# How to skip entire filter chain and let the request to go to controller

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have quite a long servlet filter chain, around 10 filters in multiple modules. I have a first filter which is supposed to catch all requests used during authentication:

`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Now, I need to add new page which should be accessible without authentication (public page) and I am not sure how to do it.

My request URL is: http://domain/context/publicPage.
If I turn the filters off, I can get to controller using the request URL.

I tried in the first filter, to skip the whole filter chain and just go to controller, with 3 different approaches:

```
//HttpServletRequest request
String requestUrl = "/context/publicPage";
if(request.getRequestURI().equals(requestUrl)){
   //1: - it doesn't go to the controller, it goes to Error page for some reason
   //request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getRequestURI()).forward(request, response);
   //2: - it doesn't go to the controller, it returns blank page
   //return;
   //3: - it cause an infinite loop as because it is redirect, it is getting caught once again by the first filter
   //response.sendRedirect(requestUrl);
}
```

Do you know how I can force it to just let the request to the controller? I know that I can implement ignore the URL across all filters something like this:

```
if(shouldPerformIgnoreUrls(((HttpServletRequest) req).getRequestURI())){
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
    return;
}
```

but I would need to make changes across multiple modules in the project, which I would like to avoid if it is possible, because we have some modules we don't want to do any more changes to.

Is there any easy way to just simply pass the request from filter to controller?

I have seen a lot of similar questions on the forum but actually no solutions works for me and I am not sure why i.e. the forward on dispatcher (approach 1 in the code).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Performance? Have you measured that you will really win much?

Comment: Requirements... very old applications which we try to fit another login page to which will use different authentication, but leverage what we have already (the existing authentication filter), so we don't need to redesign basically everything... old architecture